# MVC3 script bundles just render empty script tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I view a page, all I can see is -

`<script></script>`

My _Layout.cshtml looks like

`<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/helpdesk/Scripts")"></script>`

`Application_Start()` in `Global.asxc.cs` looks like

```
protected void Application_Start() {
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();

RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using a custom directory which won't be covered by the default bundles. You would need to add a new bundle e.g.

```
var bundle = new Bundle("~/helpdesk/js", new JsMinify());
bundle.AddDirectory("~/helpdesk/js", "*.js", true);
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
```

If your custom folder was within one of the default directories e.g. `~/Content/helpdesk/js` / `~/Scripts/helpdesk/` then you wouldn't have to do this.

Comment: +1 to his anaswer plus you can troubleshoot be using    BundleTable.Bundles.GetRegisteredBundles();